# Output specific file name of css file grunt-contrib-compass

Tags: css, angularjs, sass, compass, grunt-contrib-compass

I'm trying to specify an output name of the CSS file from my grunt-contrib-compass job. The default outputs and index.css file.

**Actual Result**
<%= yeoman.app %>/specialdir/themes/index.css

**Desired Result**
<%= yeoman.app %>/specialdir/themes/my-theme.css

Gruntfile.js

```
....
compass : {
  // specialjob here
  specialjob : {
    options : {
      sassDir : '<%= yeoman.app %>/specialdir/my-theme',
      cssDir : '<%= yeoman.app %>/specialdir/themes', // should output into this folder
      relativeAssets : false,
      assetCacheBuster : false,
      raw : 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
    },
    dist : {
      options : {
        generatedImagesDir : '<%= yeoman.app %>/specialdir/images/generated'
      }
    },
    server : {
      options : {
        sourcemap : true
      }
    }
  },
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to rename your source file to `my-theme.scss` to get `my-theme.css`. Looking through *[the source](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass/blob/da1cbcb990753892fb11a2ea8c0a254bd6e0d4ef/tasks/lib/compass.js#L106)* seems like this is the default behavior.

Happy coding!

Comment: Ha, that's it! Ridiculously simple